# Push divs offscreen on hover

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to do an animation that my designers have requested. On page load, I need a regular grid and then when the user hovers over each item, one div grows larger and the other divs in that row get pushed off-screen. I've tried using various types of layouts to achieve this but I can't find a way to push the content off-screen without causing a horizontal scroll.

I don't have permission to embed images yet but here is the static [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRIHg.png) and hover [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UrBE.png) state of what I'm needing.

This is what I have done so far https://codepen.io/kierrapalmer/pen/ExVZVLN. My question is how to get the divs to go off the page on hover instead of resizing.

```css
.custom-flex-grid {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.custom-flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-left: 8.3%;
}
.custom-flex-grid .custom-cell {
  width: 16.6%;
  margin-right: 8.3%;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
.custom-flex-grid .custom-cell .description {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
  left: 180px;
  width: 360px;
}

.custom-flex-grid .custom-cell:hover {
  width: 90%;
}
.custom-flex-grid .custom-cell:hover .heading {
  width: 180px;
}
 .custom-flex-grid .custom-cell:hover .description {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-flex-grid">
      <div class="custom-cell">
        <h4 class="heading">Full Marketing & Sales Hub Implementation</h4>
        <div class="description">Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami jowl corned beef, andouille flank tongue ball tip kielbasa pastrami tri-tip meatloaf short loin beef biltong. Cow bresaola ground round strip steak fatback meatball shoulder leberkas pastrami sausage corned beef t-bone pork belly drumstick</div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-cell">
        <h4 class="heading">Lead Scoring & List Segmentation</h4>
        <div class="description">Lorem ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit , morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-cell">
        <h4 class="heading">Integration With 3rd-party Systems</h4>
        <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, hunt anything that moves or hopped up on goofballs hide when guests come over. Hide when guests come over intrigued by the shower, or stare at ceiling climb leg for stretch and use lap as chair. Hunt anything that moves flop over, leave dead animals as gifts for chase imaginary bugs, chase mice for stare at ceiling yet hopped up on goofballs.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-cell">
        <h4 class="heading">Email Creative & Marketing Campaigns</h4>
        <div class="description">Lorem ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit , morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium.</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

EDIT: In order to try and comply with StackOverflow standards, as pointed out in the comments, I have stripped my HTML down to create a bit more simple example for anyone viewing this question in the future.https://codepen.io/kierrapalmer/pen/ExVZVLN

Comment: First, this is not really a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I for one could've used a bit more simplifying! Putting only CSS (not Sass) for example would've been nice. BUT - I fiddled with it a while anyway - about an hour. My copy of your code works now locally, more or less the way I think you want it to. Try putting flex: none in the CSS for your .custom-cell elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to strip out the code to only give the amount needed to reproduce the exact situation as best as I could. Personally, I find Sass easier to read then CSS which is why I left it in that format however I can see how that might be harder if one is not familiar with the syntax.  Anyways, putting flex:none worked exactly how I was wanting. Thank you so much for your help!